# Sorting an ArrayList<String> in a TreeMap

Tags: java

I am piping in a file. I am tracking word pairs from the file. Using a treemap the keys are all sorted. However, when i add words to those keys they are not sorted.
here is the part i need help on in the process function:

```
 private static void process(){


 if(!result.containsKey(thisWord)){
            result.put(thisWord, new ArrayList<String>());

        }

        // Add nextWord to the list of adjacent words to thisWord:
        result.get(thisWord).add(nextWord); // nextword is not sorted within the key
```

thisword is sorted

nextWord is not..

Can i use Collections.sort(result); somehow? 
im just not sure how i get to the nextWord within the result to do that.
or, is there no way to do it within my situation. I would rather not change things unless you recommend it.

This is the program

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;





public class program1 {

private static List<String> inputWords = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Map<String, List<String>> result = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();



public static void main(String[] args) {


    collectInput();
    process();
    generateOutput();
}


private static void collectInput(){
   Scanner      sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
   String       word;


    while (sc.hasNext()) {                      // is there another word?
        word = sc.next();                       // get next word
        if (word.equals("---")) 
         {
            break;
           }

        inputWords.add(word);

        }

}

private static void process(){


    // Iterate through every word in our input list
    for(int i = 0; i < inputWords.size() - 1; i++){

        // Create references to this word and next word:
        String thisWord = inputWords.get(i);
        String nextWord = inputWords.get(i+1);


        // If this word is not in the result Map yet,
        // then add it and create a new empy list for it.
        if(!result.containsKey(thisWord)){
            result.put(thisWord, new ArrayList<String>());

        }

        // Add nextWord to the list of adjacent words to thisWord:
        result.get(thisWord).add(nextWord);  // need to sort nextword
      //  Collections.sort(result);

    }

 }


 private static void generateOutput()
    {

    for(Entry e : result.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":");

        // Count the number of unique instances in the list:
        Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        List<String> words = (List)e.getValue();
        for(String s : words){
            if(!count.containsKey(s)){
                count.put(s, 1);
            }
            else{
                count.put(s, count.get(s) + 1);
            }
        }

        // Print the occurances of following symbols:
        for(Entry f : count.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("      " + f.getKey() + ",  " + f.getValue() );

        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: I head a map of map would work good i am not sure how i could add a file to a map of map..

Answer (score 1):

If you want the collection of "nextword"s sorted, why not use a TreeSet rather than an ArrayList?  The only reason I can see against it is if you might have duplicates.  If duplicates are allowed, then yes, use Collections.sort on the ArrayList when you're done adding to them.  Or look in the Apache Commons or Google collection classes - I don't know them off the top of my head, but I'm sure there is a sorted List that allows duplicates in one or both of them.

Comment: I am not sure how i could use a TreeSet in place of the arraylist?

Comment: I TRIED:
private static Map<String, TreeSet<String>> result = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();

and result.put(thisWord, new TreeSet<String>());

when i try to run the program i get an error: TreeSet cannot be cast to list.

Comment: are you trying to typecast the result.get() to List. ?
This is working for me : result.get(thisword).add(nextword);

Comment: @Corey, that's because you need to change the List<String> to Set<String> in generateOutput.  However, now I look at generateOutput, I realize that you can't use a TreeSet - you need follow the other advice I gave you.

Comment: I was told to use a map of a map, but i am not sure how to add to it from the file.. can you help?

Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> m = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

Answer (score 0):

```
result.get(thisWord).add(nextWord);
Collections.sort(result.get(thisWord));
```

Answer (score 0):

Y Don't you try some thing like this

Collections.sort(inputWords);

Comment: because then it sorts the keyword to the next word and the paired words are incorrect